# How to fix `fatal error: /386/include/u.h:`?

Tags: plan9

I try to install Inferno on my Debian 10.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/doublec/inferno
$ cd inferno
$ sh Mkdirs
$ nano mkconfig
ROOT=/root/of/the/inferno/git/clone
SYSHOST=Linux
OBJTYPE=386
$ export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/Linux/386/bin
$ ./makemk.sh
```

> removing old libraries and binaries
> gcc -m32 -c -I/home/user1/inferno/Plan9/386/include -I/home/user1/inferno/include -I/home/user1/inferno/utils/include regaux.c regcomp.c regerror.c regexec.c regsub.c rregexec.c rregsub.c

After last operation I got it [output](https://pastebin.com/uEf84sXh)

Everything lib.c with fatal error:

> ...**fatal error: /386/include/u.h**...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `SYSHOST=Plan9` was not correctly changed to `SYSHOST=Linux` in `mkconfig`.

Using the default value I get the same error:

```
$ ./makemk.sh
removing old libraries and binaries
gcc -m32 -c -I/tmp/testdir/inferno/Plan9/386/include -I/tmp/testdir/inferno/include -I/tmp/testdir/inferno/utils/include regaux.c regcomp.c regerror.c regexec.c regsub.c rregexec.c rregsub.c
In file included from /tmp/testdir/inferno/Plan9/386/include/../../include/lib9.h:1,
                 from /tmp/testdir/inferno/Plan9/386/include/lib9.h:1,
                 from regaux.c:1:
/tmp/testdir/inferno/Plan9/386/include/u.h:1:10: fatal error: /386/include/u.h: No such file or directory
 #include "/386/include/u.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

With `SYSHOST=Linux` it compiles...

```
$ ./makemk.sh
removing old libraries and binaries
gcc -m32 -c -I/tmp/testdir/inferno/Linux/386/include -I/tmp/testdir/inferno/include -I/tmp/testdir/inferno/utils/include regaux.c regcomp.c regerror.c regexec.c regsub.c rregexec.c rregsub.c
ar crvs /tmp/testdir/inferno/Linux/386/lib/libregexp.a regaux.o regcomp.o regerror.o regexec.o regsub.o rregexec.o rregsub.o
a - regaux.o
a - regcomp.o
a - regerror.o
a - regexec.o
a - regsub.o
a - rregexec.o
a - rregsub.o
...
```

Comment: Yes, its work! Thanks a lot. Just I try to install plan9 first time. I'm full noob.